# swift 4, Using UIActivityViewController to share image to facebook and other app crashes

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

In my app I am trying to share large images to another apps. But when I send a large size image to like facebook the facebook comes up but it crashes. When I resize the image to a small size it doesn't crash.

I tried to share large images in the camera roll but in the camera roll it doesn't crash and shares it with original image size.

Is there a different way to do this using UIActivityViewController?

var shareImage = UIImage
shareImage.removeAll()

```
    for i in 0...deletePhotoArray.count - 1 {
        let asset = AlbumModel.allPhotos?.object(at: deletePhotoArray[i])
        let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
        options.version = .current
        options.isSynchronous = true
        options.deliveryMode = .fastFormat
        PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: asset!, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .aspectFit, options: options) { (image, info) in
            shareImage.append(image!)
        }

    }

    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareImage, applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view // so that iPads won't crash
```

Comment: did you try `networkAccessAllowed` to `true` of  PHImageRequestOptions ?

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya Why do I have to do true for that option? It says "A Boolean value that specifies whether Photos can download the requested image from iCloud"

Comment: I got such issue where my App was crashing because actual  image was not available when user select or tap on it. so With this option true I am able to fix this

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya I tried that option but it was same for me :(

Answer (score 0):

Asking for `targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize` is certainly going to get you an extremely large image! So the first piece of advice is: don't do that. 
You *might* be able to provide the data piecemeal over time by using a UIActivityItemProvider subclass.